# How can $f'(0)=0$ when $f(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

When we say $f(x)=x\, \mbox{sgn}( x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ when we say $f(x)=0$ but it is not differentiable at $x=0$. Furthermore, we say $g(x)=x^2\mbox{sgn}(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at $x=0$. But why or how? How can $f’(0)=0$ when $f(0)=0$?

Comment: I presume $f'(0)=0$ and $f(0)=0$ simultaneously does not bother you when $f(x)=x^2$. Why does it bother you here?

Comment: Observe that $f(x) = xsgn x= |x|$

Comment: $f(0)$ is the value of $f$ at $x=0$. $f^\prime(0)$ is the slope of $f$ at $x=0$. The slope can have any value when $f(0) = 0$. When $f$ is not differentiable, it means that the slope of $f$ cannot be defined at that point.

Answer (score 1):

use $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$ and $$h\ne 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The fact that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ is not strange, as noted in the comments.

In your case, if you want calculate the derivative, remember that, for $x \ne 0$:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}|x|=\frac{x}{|x|}
$$
and note that

$$
x^2 \mbox{sgn}(x)=x|x|
$$

than use the product rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}x|x|=|x|+\frac{x}{|x|}\cdot x=\frac{2x^2}{|x|}
$$

and note that the limits from left and from right of this derivative, for $x \to 0$ are all $0$.